# How to hide an image when screen gets wider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website in which, Image is shown when the screen size is small but as the screen size gets large it disappears.

The image is below search button.

Have a look [here](http://cocvidarbha.epizy.com), by changing the width of the browser.

Coding for the image:-

```
<style type="text/css">
.advt { border:none;
width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;}
.advtimg { width:100%; height:50px}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
// place your images in this array
var random_images_array = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.jpg', '4.jpg'];

function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
    path = path || 'images/advertisment/'; // default path here
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var img = imgAr[ num ];
    var imgStr = '<img class="advt" src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
    document.write(imgStr); document.close();
}

</script>
<div class="advtimg">
<script type="text/javascript">getRandomImage(random_images_array)</script>
</div>
```

Please help me Out!

Comment: the search field and button are there for me when the screen is wide.

Comment: There is image below **search** button which is only visible on small screens.

Comment: @MichaelCoker sir thank you for taking interest in this question.

Comment: use media queries

Comment: @rex sir can u help me out with coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fixed height and a variable width. change height to 100%.

**CSS**

```
.advtimg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.advt {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me out, sir.

Comment: But sir I need an image to be shown only in 50px height.

Comment: Then keep it 50px instead of 100%. but don't vary height to width aspect ratio.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me out, sir.

Comment: Glad to help. You can mark it as answer for future users.

Answer (score 1):

Change the CSS to:-

```
<style type="text/css">
.advt { border:none;
width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;}
.advtimg { width:100%; height:50px}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media queries.  I'll just use 400px as an example breakpoint where you don't want to show the image.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400 px){
    .advtimg {
        display: none;
     }
}
```

Comment: @Chiru the snippet from @chairmanmow is exactly what you need. you only have to add this css rule. this rule says, that if the viewport width is smaller than 400px, it will have whatever styles you gave the `.advtimg`. but if the viewport is wider than 400px the `.advtimg` has the style `display: none;` what means that this element is not visible. take a look here for further information: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp